# Story about two planets meant to restart human civilization in case of collapse

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a book series that plays in a distant future. Mankind has a galactic, space faring civilization that is past its prime.

If I remember correctly, this civilization was ruled by a royal family or dictator.
The story is about two different planets. They are a "failsafe" in case civilization is destroyed. They are meant to locate the other planet and restart human civilization. One of the planets was specialized on technology, the other one I am not sure, perhaps politics and philosophy or something similar. The book series deals with the struggles of saving a dying human civilization and locating the other planet in order to enable this rescue of the galactic civilization. I remember reading this book quite a long time ago, definitely around 10 years ago but can't recall the name.

Comment: A galactic empire past its prime? Didn't Asimov write something like that?

Comment: @user49069 Does sound a lot like Foundation. So if it is not what you are looking for just say it in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116287/story-where-social-development-is-an-exact-science (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 19):

This sounds like [the Foundation series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series) by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov). Two planets at the ends of the universe were set up by Hari Seldon, a [psychohistorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_(fictional)) to optimise the recovery of the [Galactic Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Empire_(Isaac_Asimov)) from a state of anarchy. The Galactic Empire was also ruled by [an Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Empire_(Isaac_Asimov)#Emperors) from the planet [Trantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trantor), the capital.

One of the planets, [Terminus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(planet)), was meant to specialise in technology and collect scientific knowledge whilst the other reportedly consisted of mentalists and psychological experts with supernatural abilities. The inhabitants of Terminus are unaware of the location of the second planet and a major part of the plot involves locating and interacting with this other planet.

Comment: Also, large parts are about the time when the galaxy was ruled by a dictator (the Mule), so that fits too.

Comment: Quite certainly the Foundation series