# Story where social development is an exact science

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book that starts with the premise that (once the population size had exceeded a certain number) the future development of mankind (revolutions and wars in so and so many years, colonization of other planets in so and so many years, and so on) could be predicted completely by applied statistics. (IIRC, they used slide rules for those exact predictions, but that is certainly owed to the time the story was written).
Next, the predictability was used to take a few tiny measures that would change mankind's fate in a favourable way.
After a long time, the predictive system fails(?) because a mutation occurs in some person(s).

And now is the part where I'm not sure if it belongs to this or another story: The mutation results in the ability to "beam" by thinking of a place where one has been before...

Comment: The first part seems to point to Asimov's _Foundation_ cycle, with its concept of [_psychohistory_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_%28fictional%29), but I don't remember any "beaming" ...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(Foundation) would be the mutation in that case, but in his case, it was mind control, "mentalics".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would likely be Asimov's *[Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series)* series, where a central premise was the idea of [Psychohistory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_(fictional)), the idea that, as a whole, humans are predictable, so you really can figure out the trends.

[The Mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(Foundation)) is a mutant who can literally change peoples' minds for them. His mutation allows him to exert a greater influence than any individual ought to be able to in the predictive model and yes, it throws the system off (although a "Second Foundation" gets it back up and running).

Comment: That's it exactly. The "mental beaming mutation" must be another story then (but at least it was a "mental something mutation")

Answer (score 4):

> The mutation results in the ability to "beam" by thinking of a place
> where one has been before...

I wonder if you're combining Foundation with the Null-A series by Van Vogt, in which Gilbert Gosseyn has the ability to teleport, requiring that he remember the location that he wants to go to, to "twenty-decimal similarity".